# Can I use a flag like -l from ls with find or locate?

Tags: command-line-interface

Is there a way to display all the information that -l does in ls (permissions, dates, etc.) when using the locate or find commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not just for "ls -l" but for whatever action you'd want to perform to your locate or find results you can use xargs or in the case of find the -exec flag. Here are examples to achieve what you want to do:

In the case of locate you can use xargs:

```
locate something | xargs ls -l
```

Xargs can be used for find too, but find has the -exec flag that allow to optimize further actions with find results; for example

```
find . -iname something -exec ls -l '{}' \;
```

Comment: This is the more general approach compare to mine.  But I would generally recommend to use `xargs` for find as well, as it handles large result sets better (`-exec` spawns a new process for every file while `xargs` groups them to create as few processes as possible).

Comment: When find returns a huge amount of lines you might have problems to buffer all of them. Also with -exec you process the result as soon as it appears and you don't have to wait the end of the find process to start the xargs part.

Comment: if execing things I find it better to use `+` e.g. `find . -exec ls -l '{}' +`. This reduces the number of calls to exec as + puts many of the files found on one command line.

Comment: xargs starts working as soon as it has enough data.

Comment: Awesome - this is exactly what I wanted to know and am going to go learn more about xargs. Thanks!

Comment: Watch out if `something` matches a directory then the `ls -l` prints the contents of the directory too ;)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you want to do, but try

```
find . -ls
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-printf` and a suitable format string

```
 find ./ -printf "%M\t%n\t%u\t%g\t%s\t%t%f\n"
```

- %M Symbolic permissions
- %n hard links
- %u username or numeric user id
- %g group name or numeric group id
- %s file size in bytes
- %t last modification time
- %f filename

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
find | while read a; do ls -l "$a"; done
```